# Where is Shellrevealed

Tags: windows

As a new shell developer I came across many new articles that have links and
examples from a website called Shellrevealed.com

Unfortunately all of those links are dead as Shellrevealed itself can not
be found anywhere.

My question is, did they really shutdown or did they change their url????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this particular site has been shutdown...

Try your luck @the Internet Archive ...

```
http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://shellrevealed.com
```

Comment: Thanks man, well yes I guess they've closed but I've asked this question not only to see if Shellrevealed has moved. But also to see if somebody out there knows any similar sites

Answer (score 2):

You can still find some (if not all) of their samples at

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ShellRevealed

Comment: One of the files is especially interesting: archive_blog_shellRevealed.chm: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=ShellRevealed&DownloadId=7355 - it's actually the whole blog archive.

Comment: These links are now dead as well, did anyone manage to save them while they were still working?